# Django ORM query to calculate score from number of votes and days passed

Tags: django, orm

I am currently working on a 9gag-like site, where users submit content, and then upvote/downvote the content.

On the front page, I would like to show all articles, that were published no later that 5 days ago and have at least 2 votes. My UserArticle model has a `published_at field(A DateTimeField)`, and I have a **model called `UserVote` which stores the votes** for the article. I have accomplished that with the following code:

```
def article_index(request):

    time_threshold = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=5)

    articles =(UserArticle.objects.annotate(num_votes=Sum('uservote__value'))
        .filter(num_votes__gte=2, published_at__gte=time_threshold)
        .order_by('-num_votes')
    )
```

My only problem left is how the posts are sorted. It is currently sorted in descending order with the highest number of votes first.

In addition to being sorted by the highest number of votes, **I would like to penalize older articles by the factor of days since it was published**.

Something like: `num_votes + age_in_days_since_publication*(-2)`.

Comment: `.order_by('-num_votes', 'published_at')`?

Comment: This is a good suggestion, and I did consider this solution myself. My biggest issue is that I would like to be able to determine how heavily older posts should be penalized by a factor.